# Rewrite a Logarithm as a product of logarithms

Tags: logarithms

Can anyone help me to understand this?

$$\log_2 n = \log_2e \log n$$

Comment: Change of base: $\log_r a = \frac{\log_s a}{\log_s r}$ and implicitly, in your notation: $\log = \log_e$, sometimes written as $\ln$.

Comment: $$2^{\log_2n}=2^{\log_2e\log n}=(2^{\log_2e})^{\log n}=e^{\log n}.$$

Comment: Do you want to understand the formula itself, or gain a feel for why logarithms in different bases are similar this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\log_r(n)$ is the number such that $r^{\log_r(n)} = n$. Taking the $\log_s$ on both sides we have that
$$
\log_s\left(r^{\log_r(n)}\right) = \log_s(n) \implies \log_r(n) \log_s(r) = \log_s(n).
$$
In your case, let $s = 2$ and $ r = e $.